# Who is using PST file in my organization SCCM

Tags: outlook, active-directory, sccm, pst

I need to find out who is using PST file in my organization.
i thougt maybe it easier to fo it using `SCCM 2012 query`.

but i didn't found any help on google.

the search need to contain the path:

```
C:\Users\*user*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook
```

can anyone help me?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Software inventory

Before everything, you need to enable software inventory and create rules in your environment.
Go to **Administration** - **Client Settings** - **Default Client Setting** properties- **Software Inventory**, Click **Set Types**... Click **New** to add a path for querying, here you can add C:\Users\ and file name as *.pst and save.  More instruction of software inventory rule, see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc181215.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[image]

After next Software inventory cycle finished (default is 7 days, you can manual trigger on client side by **Control panel** - **Configuration Manager** - **Actions** - **Software Inventory Cycle**), data will be collected and saved in database. Then you can use SQL query or built-in reports to get what you want. Example query like below:

```
 select distinct   
      Sys.Name0,  
      SF.FileName AS [Filename],  
      SF.ModifiedDate AS [Last Modified Date],  
      SF.Filepath AS [Local Filepath],  
      SF.FileSize/1024 as [Size (MB)],  
      SF.FileSize/1024000000 as [Size (GB)]  
 from v_R_System Sys   
      INNER JOIN v_GS_SoftwareFile SF on  
 Sys.ResourceID = SF.ResourceID  
      INNER JOIN v_FullCollectionMembership FCM on  
 FCM.ResourceID=sys.ResourceID  
      where SF.FileName like '%'+'.pst'  
      Order by SF.FileName
```

**Attention**, software inventory is a file by file scanning so it will need long time to complete and may cost more computer resource; During the inventory period, other inventory like heart beat inventory, hardware inventory will on hold till software inventory complete.

About Software inventory on Technet, see [About Software Inventory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg682126.aspx)
[See here for implementation example](https://itdiplomat.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/pst-inventory-with-sccm/)

Also, Script working with hardware inventory can collect all these information as well. I found a good solution and it worked well in my lab, see [Example](http://myitforum.com/myitforumwp/2013/04/20/configmgr-inventory-who-is-using-outlook-pst-files-where-are-they-and-how-big-are-they/)

Comment: thanks for the reply! 
i have one client settings and i think i have Software inventory check there. is this the full query that i need? i get an error massage

Comment: My query is based on the rule I wrote above, querying C:\Users\\*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook*.pst, then all .pst files will be collected. When software inventory complete, the query should work. What's your query rule? Normally, software inventory will take hours or even more. You can check on client side InventoryAgent.log to monitor for software inventory process.

Comment: Have you been able to complete the query?